# Webpack 3 - Writing styles to a CSS file

Tags: webpack, webpack-style-loader, extract-text-plugin, extracttextwebpackplugin

I have read tons of tutorials and looked at more Github repos than I care to remember but I'm really struggling to setup Webpack 3 to do the following:

- Compile SASS into CSS
- Create a CSS file within a dist directory
- Run Autoprefixer on CSS

Below is my webpack.config.js:

```
const path = require('path')
const webpack = require('webpack')
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin')

module.exports = {
    context: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
        entry: {
        app: './js/index.js',
    },
    output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        publicPath: '/dist',                          // New
    },
    devServer: {
        contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),    // New
    },

    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/i,
                exclude: [/node_modules/],
                use: [{
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: { presets: ['env'] },
                }],
            },
            {
              test: /\.css$/,
              use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                fallback: "style-loader",
                use: "css-loader"
              })
            },
            {
              test: /\.(sass|scss)$/i,
              use: [
                'style-loader',
                'css-loader',
                'sass-loader',
              ]
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
      new ExtractTextPlugin({
        filename: 'css/styles.css',
        allChunks: true,
      }),
    ]
};
```

At the moment:

- the webpack dev server is running.
- Styles are copied from src/scss/styles.scss to an inline style block within the HTML file served from src/index.html.

I would like a dist directory to be created with a styles.css file within it which I could then link to from within my HTML.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

> Compile SASS into CSS

You are currently correctly compiling SASS into CSS with

```
{
  test: /\.(sass|scss)$/i,
  use: [
    'style-loader',
    'css-loader',
    'sass-loader'
  ]
}
```

> Create a CSS file within a dist directory

The CSS is not being extracted into an external file because of `style-loader` in the previously described loader chain. [`style-loader`](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/style-loader/#src/components/Sidebar/Sidebar.jsx) internalizes all CSS passed to it within a `<style>`.

To create an external file you can use, which you are, `extract-text-webpack-plugin`. The only problem is that it is not attached to the `/\.(sass|scss)$/` test.

You only need to create rules for your source files. Since you are writing SASS/SCSS, you do not need a `/\.css$/` test. Your CSS should be extracted if you change your loader chain to

```
{
  test: /\.(sass|scss)$/i,
  use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
    fallback: 'style-loader',
    use: [
      'css-loader',
      'sass-loader'
    ]
  })
}
```

> Run Autoprefixer on CSS

Now, to autoprefix your CSS, you'll need to add another loader into the chain, [`postcss-loader`](https://github.com/postcss/postcss-loader). Install it along with `autoprefixer`.

```
npm i -D postcss-loader autoprefixer
```

Add the require for `autoprefixer` at the top of your `webpack.config.js`.

```
const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
```

Finally, add `postcss-loader` to the loader chain, [**in between `css-loader` and `sass-loader`**](https://github.com/postcss/postcss-loader#config-cascade).

```
use: [
  'css-loader',
  {
    loader: 'postcss-loader',
    options: {
      plugins: [autoprefixer()]
    }
  },
  'sass-loader'
]
```

Comment: A great answer as you've explained where I was going wrong and why. Unfortunately the CSS file still isn't being generated. I've pasted my amended webpack.config.js into a Codepen. Would be really grateful if someone could give it a quick view: https://codepen.io/decodedcreative/pen/XVWNZe

Comment: Do you happen to have a repo for this project?

Comment: I've just set one up: https://github.com/decodedcreative/react-webpack-boilerplate. Thanks for looking at this, its been driving me crazy!

Comment: Ahh. Your `start` script is running `webpack-dev-server` which doesn't write any files to disk, as it serves all files in memory. Use `webpack` to generate bundled files and `webpack-dev-server` for a live-reloading development environment.